# Torbrowser opens downloads in firefox

Tags: linux

Today I downloaded a picture with Tor (4.5.3 (based on Mozilla Firefox 31.8.0)) and opened it in the Download-tab.

Strangely it didn't open it with the default-file opener but with the regular Firefox. I'm a bit puzzled and tried to change the file-types under the Applications (Anwendungen)-Tab within settings. Doesn't seem to be possible?

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this issue here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/370110/switched-from-unity-to-cinnamon-now-firefox-opens-wrong-app-from-downloads-menu

Apparently it was not Tor's mistake but somehow a wrongly set entry in:

> /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
>
> `image/jpeg=firefox.desktop;gimp.desktop;kde4-okularApplication_kimgio.desktop;org.kde.gwenview.desktop;display-im6.q16.desktop;display-im6.desktop;rawtherapee.desktop;geeqie.desktop;`